# Proper tokenize string in C

Tags: c, string, tokenize

I have the folowing condition:

```
else if (strcmp(strtok(line, " "), "*") == 0)
```

I want to read some chars of an stdin line and do some stuff depending on the first char.In this case I just want to read a line with a single char " * ". This condition won't be true only if on stdin i'll pass "* " (star and a space).I want to pass only "*".What can I do?

Comment: Can't you just `if(line[0] == '*')`?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked